# ember broccoli foundation-sites

Tags: node.js, ember.js, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

When try to **ember build** or **ember serve** I get next error:

**The Broccoli Plugin: [SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/vendor.js] failed with:**

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   '/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/tmp/**source_map_concat-input_base_path-TNdPSywn.tmp**/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js'
>       at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:906:18)
>       at FSMonitor._measure (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:66:21)
>       at Object.statSync (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:82:30)
>       at Concat.keyForFile (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:87:20)
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at Concat.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:109:65)
>       at /Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:93:34
>       at tryCatch (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
>       at invokeCallback (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
>       at publish (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
>       at flush (/Users/artem_shevtsov/DATA/Projects/laser/ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

I tried npm and bower cache clean, **rm -rf tmp node_modules bower_components** and plugins reinstallation

Also tried manual installation with npm and bower (**npm i foundation-sites, bower install foundation-sites**) and add

> app.import('node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js')
>   app.import('node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js')

(or bower_components/... respectively) but it does not work

> ❯ npm -v
>   3.10.9
>
> ❯ node -v
>   v7.2.0
>
> ❯ ember -v
>   v7.2.0
>   ember-cli: 2.9.0 
>   node: 7.2.0 
>   os: darwin x64

Comment: show your package.json and bower.json

Comment: You can only `app.import` from `vendor` and `bower_components`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app.import('bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js', {
>       type: 'vendor'
>     });

**type: 'vendor'** is the secret of success

path can be different, depends on foundation-sites version

I leave **package.json** and **bower.json** without any changes

Comment: yep, this is a hotfix ... but for a long term I would say it is better to leave ember plugin for foundation and use vanilla foundation-sites

Answer (score 0):

- Remove entry for `foundation` or `foundation-sites` from package.json and bower.json.
- npm cahce clean
- bower cache clean
- rm -rf tmp node_modules bower_components
- npm install && bower install
- bower install foundation
- remove other entries related foundation from ember-cli-build.js and include below `app.import('bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js')`
- Stop ember server and start it again.

Comment: I did so before, and tried once more now. It still does not work :(

Comment: I would say, have coffee break and try it later :)

Comment: I have them whole day (while npm install is running)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the version of foundation-sites to 6.2.2 in bower.json
2. run `bower install`